# Completely wrong tax calculation

Tags: tax

I have set up a tax rate of 21% (Belgian Tax). This tax rate applies to all products (Taxable Goods) through the needed Tax Rule.

Let's take a product with a price of 6.82€ (tax included). Magento shows "[Inc. Tax €1.18]" on the *Price* tab for this product.

This is completely wrong: 6.82€ * 0.21 = 1.4322€ (-> compared to 1.18€)

As a result, the tax information on the shopping cart and on invoices are totally wrong.

I have this set-up in System > Configuration > Tax:

- Tax Calculation Method Based On: Total
- Tax Calculation Based On: Shipping Origin
- Catalog Prices: Including Tax
- Shipping Prices: Including Tax
- Apply Customer Tax: Before Discount
- Apply Discount On Prices: Excluding Tax
- Apply Tax On: Custom price if available

I can't find what is going wrong. Any help would be fully appreciated.

Comment: What version of Magento are you currently using? Do you have any other tax rates set?

Comment: Magento CE 1.7.0.2. No other tax rates set.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Actually the numbers are ok. 6.82 Including tax means that 6.82 = 1.21 * (price_without_tax).
This means that price without tax = 6.82 / 1.21 = 5.64.
And the tax is 6.82 - 5.64 = 1.18.

Comment: Dude. I was making wrong calculations! Thanks Marius, I read your answer and then hit my head on the wall.

Comment: I am facing one issue with tax. 
Product price = 5 USD (Including tax)
We have configured tax 5% for specific country, region (Country - India , State - Maharashtra).

Displayed price as Including tax - for more information of the issue you can review  http://i.stack.imgur.com/Woza2.jpg link.

Comment: @BijalBhavsar. The calculations are right.  You have the prices set to include tax. 5% in your case. this means that 10INR is the product price with 5% tax included. This means that the tax value is  (10/(100+5)) *5 = 0.476 ~ 0.48.

Comment: @marius - could you please elaborate logic of this calculation.

Comment: @BijalBhavsar. This is how the taxes work. If your product price has the taxes included, the tax amount is calculated as this:  (productPrice / (100 + taxPercent)) * taxPercent. Or in a more friendly way (productPrice*taxPercent) / (100 + taxPercent).

Comment: Hello Marius, can you see below calculations and let me know if they are right for 21* Tax 
Subtotal €196.32
Shipping & Handling €7.40
Kosten betaalmethode €7.40
Grand Total (Excl.Tax) €209.84
Tax
€44.11
Grand Total (Incl.Tax) €253.95 Total Paid €0.00
Total Refunded €0.00
Total Due €253.95